# issues with firing a link button click event within a gridview in a vb asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, webforms, asplinkbutton

I have web application created with VB Visual Studio 2008. I have a created a new page to display a grid view showing contracts from a database with a certain status. In the grid view i have an item template field with a link button. The default text for the link button is Add.

When the button is clicked, i would like to add the id number of the contract from the db to a list of integers. If the contract id is present on the list, the text of the button should read as 'Remove' and it should then be removed from the list. if it is not present in the list, the text of the button should read as 'add' and it should be added to the list.  In the click event for the button, i have the code to achieve this.

The page loads fine and displays the items in the grid view, however when i click the add button it was generating a null exception error pointing to my casting the link button. I then put the grid view in an update panel, and i no longer get the null exception error but now nothing happens.

here is aspx code & vb code for the grid view. the null error was firing on the line with  Dim btnT As New LinkButton and the next line with btnT = CType(sender, LinkButton). Any assistance will be greatly appreciated, the strange thing is have very similar code (i practically duplicated the code) in a vb asp.net web site, and it works fine.

```
       <td align="center"> 
            <div class="style82">
                Contract Queue
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div class = "queue">
                <div class="status">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="MainUpdate" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>                            
                            <div>
                                <asp:GridView ID="grdvContract" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
                                    AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" 
                                    BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" 
                                    Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Small" 
                                    ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" PageSize="25" Width="100%"
                                    OnRowDataBound="grdvContract_RowDataBound">
                                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#333300" BorderColor="#FF5050" BorderStyle="Solid" 
                                        ForeColor="#FF9900" />
                                    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="dealno" HeaderText="Deal No" SortExpression="dealno" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type" SortExpression="Type" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Currency" HeaderText="Currency" 
                                            SortExpression="Currency" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Amount" HeaderText="Amount" 
                                            DataFormatString="{0:#,###,###.00}" SortExpression="Amount" HtmlEncode="false" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" 
                                            SortExpression="Status" />
                                        <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="dealno"   Text='<img src="graphics/txt.gif" border="0" />'
                                            DataNavigateUrlFormatString="deal_ticket_standard.aspx?id={0}" 
                                            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"  
                                            HeaderText="Standard View"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"  Target="javascript:window.open ('deal_ticket_standard.aspx?id={0}', 'win', 'height=400,width=400,location=no,menubar=no,resizable,scrollbars,status=no,toolbar=no');">
                                            <HeaderStyle Width="50" />
                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"/>
                                        </asp:HyperLinkField> 
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="rate" HeaderText="Rate" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="rate"/>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="cDate" HeaderText="Contract Date" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="cDate" />
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Action" >
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnAction" runat="server" Text = "Add" AutoPostBack = "False"
                                                OnClick = "btnAction_Click" CausesValidation="False"></asp:LinkButton>    
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>                                   
                                    </Columns>
                                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                                </asp:GridView>                                                                  
                            </div>
                            <div id="ActionStatus" runat="server" visible="false" class="status">
                                ** <asp:Literal ID="ltActionSuccess" runat="server"></asp:Literal> **
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <br />                
                                Total Deals to be included in this file: <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" class="total" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                <br />                            
                            </div>
                        </ContentTemplate>                                                                    
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="MainUpdateProgress" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="MainUpdate">
                        <ProgressTemplate>
                            <div >
                                Please wait, loading updated content...
                            </div>            
                        </ProgressTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdateProgress>
                </div>
            </div>               
        </td>...
```

Imports System.Data

Partial Public Class contract_queue
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

```
Private _DealList As List(Of Integer)

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        DealList = New List(Of Integer)
        FillContractQueue()
    End If

End Sub

Public Property DealList() As List(Of Integer)
    Get
        Return _DealList
    End Get

    Set(ByVal value As List(Of Integer))
        _DealList = value
    End Set

End Property

Protected Sub grdvContract_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles grdvContract.RowDataBound

    Dim grid_row As GridViewRow
    grid_row = e.Row

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        Dim deal_no As Integer = CInt(DataBinder.Eval(grid_row.DataItem, "dealno"))

        Dim btnR As LinkButton = grid_row.FindControl("btnAction")
        btnR.Attributes.Add("dealid", deal_no)

        'If DealList.Contains(dealno) Then
        '    btnR.Text = "Remove"

        'Else
        '    btnR.Text = "Add"
        'End If

    End If

End Sub
Protected Sub btnAction_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Me.ActionStatus.Visible = True
    Me.ltActionSuccess.Text = "Test"
    Dim total As Integer = 0
    total = DealList.Count
    Me.lblTotal.Text = total


    Dim btnT As New LinkButton
    btnT = CType(sender, LinkButton)
    Dim deal_id As Integer = btnT.Attributes("dealid")


    If DealList.Contains(deal_id) Then
        DealList.Remove(deal_id)
        btnT.Text = "Add"
        total = DealList.Count
        Me.ltActionSuccess.Text = "Deal " & deal_id & " added to file"
        Me.lblTotal.Text = total
    Else
        DealList.Add(deal_id)
        total = DealList.Count
        btnT.Text = "Remove"
        Me.ltActionSuccess.Text = "Deal " & deal_id & " removed from file"
        Me.lblTotal.Text = total
    End If


End Sub
Protected Sub FillContractQueue()
    Dim ContractDeals As New DataSet()

    'set up db connection'
    Dim strConnect As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ibl_treasuryConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Dim objConnection As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(strConnect)

    Dim strQuery As String
    strQuery = "SELECT convert(varchar, t_deal_register.contractdate, 106) AS cDate, t_deal_register.id AS dealno, t_deal_type.dealtype AS Type, t_client.client_name AS Client, t_dealer_ibl.dealer_ibl + '/' + t_dealer_client.dealer_client AS Dealers, t_deal_register.amount AS Amount, t_deal_register.fxrate AS rate, t_status.Status, t_currency.currency + '/' + t_currency_1.currency AS Currency FROM t_deal_register INNER JOIN t_deal_type ON t_deal_register.dealtype = t_deal_type.id INNER JOIN t_client ON t_deal_register.clientname = t_client.id INNER JOIN t_dealer_ibl ON t_deal_register.dealer_ibl = t_dealer_ibl.id INNER JOIN t_dealer_client ON t_deal_register.dealer_client = t_dealer_client.id INNER JOIN t_currency ON t_deal_register.currency = t_currency.id INNER JOIN t_status ON t_deal_register.status = t_status.id INNER JOIN t_currency AS t_currency_1 ON t_deal_register.pay_currency = t_currency_1.id where t_deal_register.status = '14' ORDER BY t_deal_register.id DESC"
    Dim objCommand As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(strQuery, objConnection)

    objConnection.Open()
    Try
        Dim DealAdapter As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(objCommand)
        DealAdapter.Fill(ContractDeals)

    Catch ex As Exception
        Me.lblMessage.Text = ex.Message

    Finally
        objConnection.Close()

        If ContractDeals.Tables.Count > 0 Then
            grdvContract.DataSource = ContractDeals
            grdvContract.DataBind()
        End If
    End Try

End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

```
     <asp:TemplateField>
                     <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkButtonID" runat="server"
                             OnClick="lnkButton_Click"  Text='<%#DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(Container.DataItem, "ID")%>'
                             name = '<%#DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(Container.DataItem, "Name")%>'
                             address = '<%#DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(Container.DataItem, "address")%>'
                             description = '<%#DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(Container.DataItem, "Description")%>'
                         ></asp:LinkButton>
                     </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Code dumps are not useful answers. For a useful answer, say *what* you changed, and *why*.